# Ionic 2 - ionViewDidLoad function cant read navCtrl

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am using localForage to store local data in my app. So I check when screen is loaded `if value = true` when it is the page has to be redirected to my TabsPage.

Here is the constructor:

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loading: LoadingController){}
```

Here is my ionViewLoaded function:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  localForage.getItem('didLogin', function(err, value) {
     // Run this code once the value has been
     // loaded from the offline store.
     console.log(value);

     if(value){
        this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
     }
  });
}
```

In an other function it is working with the same code line.

This is the error which I get:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the 'this' inside your callback is not an instance of the parent component. The function changes it.
You can use ES6 arrow function that will keep the this from the parent

```
localForage.getItem('didLogin', (err, value) => {
 if(value){
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
 }
});
```

The problem is not the ionViewDidLoad, if you call the this.navCtrl outside the localForage.getItem it will work.

You can read more about arrow function (and the 'this' issue) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).